# Как обработать изображения с помощью Numpy и Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Ребята, привет! Очень нужна помощь! Как можно подгрузить изображения и сохранить их, предварительно обработав с помощью данных функций?
В итоге мне нужно получить случайно обработанные изображения(сдвиг, поворот).
P.s.: Прошу прощение если вопрос оформлен не правильно
[image: фрагмент кода]
[image: фрагмент кода]

Comment: Если код важен, он должен быть текстом. Но вообще, что-то его слишком много, чтобы он был важен. [mcve].

Comment: @Qwertiy, нашел на просторах github [вот здесь](https://github.com/outlace/Data-Augmentation) Если можете помочь, буду признателен. Сам, к сожалению, не смог справиться

Comment: Помочь не могу, в этих технологиях не разбираюсь.

Comment: Любой текст лучше вставлять в вопрос как текст - картинки имеют свойство удаляться с хостингов, плохо отображаться на мобилах, нельзя выделить текст и скопировать себе, также поиск по картинкам не работает и люди с похожей проблемой не смогут найти вопрос. Для работы с изображениями можно взять Pillow - там есть и поворот, и сдвиг, и все это разными методами, и еще море всего для картинок.

Comment: @IvanIlichev, а в чем у вас возникли проблемы? По вашей ссылке вроде бы вполне понятные примеры...

Answer (score 1):

Привествую. 
Советую воспользоваться модулем PIL, позволяющему загружать фотографии в виде двухмерных массивом и, впоследствии, сохранять их соотвествующими методами:

```
from PIL import Image # Подключим необходимые библиотеки. 
image = Image.open("example.jpg") # Открываем изображение. 
image.save("result.jpg", "JPEG") # Сохраняем изображение, после действий с ним.
```